# How can I load a local HTML file instead of a web page in Xcode webview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios

Hey!
How can I load a local html file saved to the project instead of a webpage in this code:

```
- (void)loadAboutHTML {
UIWebView *aboutHTML = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
NSURL *webURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://apple.com"];
NSURLRequest *webURLRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:webURL];
[aboutHTML loadRequest:webURLRequest];
[aboutHTML setScalesPageToFit:YES];
[aboutHTML setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 416)];
[self addSubview:aboutHTML];}
```

Comment: You need to accept the correct answer.

Comment: @elpsk upvoted all helpful ones, posted my own answer based on all of them

Comment: Kind of does the people who answered the question a disservice to upvote in order to answer your own question with their responses? Just saying it's probably not the best practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**OPTION 1**

Use this

```
- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
```

Read the contents of the file in your project into an `NSString`. Then use the above method to load the html content

Use

```
+ (id)stringWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error
```

to obtain the string from the file and then use

```
[webView loadHTMLString:urHTMLString baseURL:baseURL];
```

**OPTION 2**

```
NSURLRequest *urlReq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fileName" ofType:@"html"]]];
[webView loadRequest:urlReq];
```

**UPDATE**

```
- (void)loadAboutHTML {
UIWebView *aboutHTML = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourFileName" ofType:@"html"]]];
[aboutHTML loadRequest:urlRequest;
[self addSubview:aboutHTML];
}
```

Comment: @problem child
hey guys! thank you very very much but none of these methods worked for me :/
could You maybe take the code I wrote up there and modify it to show me how it's done?

Comment: Add your html file to the projects resources bundle and use this code.

Answer (score 14):

```
UIWebView *web = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
[web loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                            pathForResource:@"help" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
web.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

thats wat i had used

Answer (score 2):

local web html

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]                                                                           pathForResource:@"file_name_html" ofType:@"html"] isDirectory:NO]]];
```

http web

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]]];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
may be the answer of the solution

CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    applicationFrame.origin.y = 0;
    webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:applicationFrame];
    webView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);

    NSString *basePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:basePath];
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
    NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    if (htmlString) {
        [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
    }

    [self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 UIWebView *agreementView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, newY, 494, 300)];
        agreementView.delegate = self;
        agreementView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeNone;
        [agreementView  loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourfilename" ofType:@"html"]]]];
        loadingIndicator=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        loadingIndicator.frame=CGRectMake(237, 140, 20, 20);
        loadingIndicator.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.55, 1.55);
        [agreementView addSubview:loadingIndicator];
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    loadingIndicator.hidden=NO;
    [loadingIndicator startAnimating];

}
//delegates
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    loadingIndicator.hidden=YES;
    [loadingIndicator stopAnimating];

}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [loadingIndicator stopAnimating];
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{


    if(UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther == navigationType)
    {
    return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```