# Error Handling Page of PhoneGap in IOS

Tags: ios, cordova

I created an `iPhone` `phone gap` app it opens `url` in webView , sometimes there is no internet connection or the request returns with `404 page not found` or the `url` is corrupted and the app returns blank white page...

I have released a build in `android` before and i solved this case in this way :

```
<!-- Inside config.xml of android app -->
<!-- in this case while 404 it well redirect automatically to error.html -->
<preference name="errorURL" value="file:///android_asset/www/error.html" />
```

what is the similar solution in IOS ??? what is the best approach for this case …

Comment: I don't know Android very well, is `file:///android_asset/www/error.html` your custom file? In that case, add one to your iOS application as well and refer to it. It might be nice to check [Creating User Friendly 404 Pages](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/creating-user-friendly-404-pages.html)

Comment: @M.Mimpen Yes I created this page in my Project and i used it as 404 Handler page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make a hard research for may problem i found the answer and i like to share it you well find the solution in this link [How can I load a local HTML file instead of a web page in Xcode webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935955/how-can-i-load-a-local-html-file-instead-of-a-web-page-in-xcode-webview)

and i solved my problem with these steps :

1. I created `error.html` in `www` folder.
2. in `MainViewController.m` : i located `didFailLoadWithError` method and remove comments form it and write this code below :

   ```
   (void) webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError*)error 
   {
       [theWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"error" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"www"] isDirectory:NO]]]; 
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1. I created error.html in www folder under staging folder in Xcode.
2. I make a change in config.xml under staging folder in Xcode as follow

`<preference name="errorURL" value="error.html" />`

in MainViewController.m : i created didFailLoadWithError method (see example below :

```
-(void) webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError*)error 
{
[theWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"error" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"www"] isDirectory:NO]]]; 
}
```

Thanks to **@Abu taha** because i borrowed a little bit of his idea